# Logic for cross browser testing using @dataprovider in TestNG - Selenium - Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, parameters, testng, testng-dataprovider

There are similar questions out there but no solution.

I am looking for a way to use @Parameter annotation (for cross browser logic) and @Dataprovider annotation (for data driven logic) simultaneously in a single @Test.

I don't think there is any way to use both of them together, but what is the approach for cross browser testing in this case ??

Note: I don't want to run tests on all browsers everytime, so putting browser type in dataprovider is not an option.

Comment: awaiting expert comments

Comment: try [qaf](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#frameworks) you can configure one or multiple browsers through xml config file.